# What does "flight" and "stairs" means in "a flight of stairs" respectively?

Tags: word-meaning

According to the dictionary, "a stair" can either mean "a step" or "a set of steps".

> Terry was sitting on the bottom stair. (A stair is one of the steps in a flight of stairs.)
>
> I followed her down the stair. (A stair is a flight of stairs.)

My first question is why does "stair" have a meaning of both plural and singular?

The second question is what is the origin of "flight" in the context of "a flight of stairs"?
I am curious about how could the meaning of "fly" be transformed to "a sequence of"?

Thanks!

Comment: It's quite common to hear the following: "To  fly up the stairs" often in religious contexts, stairs lead to heaven or to paradise. Think of Led Zepellion and their iconic song, [*Stairway to heaven*](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd1-nn1ZjPAhVJC8AKHbX9AvAQyCkIHzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8pPvNqOb6RA&usg=AFQjCNFhCqqrRObp1b3WOPekm-2dTQrrwQ&sig2=TwqevJq6r5q5dH7vb--O4Q&bvm=bv.133178914,d.ZGg) Note the singular "stairway".

Comment: Languages develop over centuries.  Some speakers have referred to the stairway as the **stair**, and some have referred to it as a set of **stairs**.  Both words have been in use for over 700 years.

Comment: Which dictionary are you quoting? Could you please provide a link to this definition?

Comment: Also  note that questions concerning the origin of words are off-topic on ELL.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I'm quoting from [COBUILD](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stair).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the origin of "flight" in the context of "a flight of stairs"

In the Book of Genesis, there is the story about Jacob fleeing from his brother Esau. One night he dreamt of angels climbing up and down a ladder, and then he saw God standing at the top.

Western artists; however, preferred not to depict a precarious ladder leading to heaven, the majority opted to represent this structure as a stairway, or a staircase.

[image]

The verb *[flee](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flee?q=flee)* in Old English meant "to take flight, fly from, escape", the verb *fly*, meaning "flight", (not its older meaning to have wings and soar in the air) came later in the mid 15th century. Since c.1200 the word **flight** also means the act of *fleeing*; but it wasn't until 1703 when it came to mean a "series of stairs between landings". [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=flight)

> In the case of a "flight of stairs" meaning a series of steps between landings, the usage dates back to the beginning of the **18th century**, and may well have been a borrowing of the French phrase "*volee d'escalier*." As defined in the Oxford English Dictionary, a "flight" in this sense is "a series of steps, terraces, etc., ascending without change of direction,"...
>   *[Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/060807B.html)*

Comment: Great, except, "[ELL]  is not the right site for questions about: Etymology, evolution of the English language, or historical English - see english.stackexchange.com instead."

Comment: @AlanCarmack, out of interest, where is the page that says what is and is not off topic?

Comment: @dan_waterworth See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Excellent!! I think this is THE best answer for me even if it's out off topic. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native English speaker. I've never heard 'stair' (singular) used.

A "flight of stairs" is an uninterrupted set of steps. Flight in this context is the act of travelling through the air without stopping. This is related to the way 'flight' is used in air travel: an unbroken journey in an aircraft is called a 'flight'.

Comment: You can find a singular stair in the poem *"Yesterday, upon the stair, / I met a man who wasn't there. / He wasn't there again today, / I wish, I wish he'd go away."* But it's probably singular only because of the rhyme.

Comment: Both singular and plural forms, **stair** and **stairs**, can refer to the entire flight. In contemporary American English, the plural is by far the more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=footsteps+on+the+stair%2Cfootsteps+on+the+stairs&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfootsteps%20on%20the%20stair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfootsteps%20on%20the%20stairs%3B%2Cc0